I can no longer upload images from my site after server migration
I have a website hosted on an Ionos VPS. It is a site developed with Node, a frontend and a backend. File management is managed with the Multer and Sharp packages. I have no errors in the logs, neither for node nor for nginx.
4 days ago, ionos migrated their servers, including mine. Following this migration, I can no longer upload any images from my site.
I contacted them to tell them about my problem, but as there was no error on their side, it must be mine. I spent three days searching and still haven't found where it came from.
I was thinking about insufficient write rights, so I put the folder (/var/www/SITE/frontend/public/images) in 775 with www-data in group and MY-USER in user (which is in the www-data group).
But it still doesn't work. It seems to me that I had to do something similar when I put the site online a year ago, but I don't remember.
I know it's not easy to be able to help me like that (especially since I'm not sure I'm really clear in my explanation), but if sometimes you think of something, I'm interested because I really dries!!!
Many thanks in advance.
Mickael
I put the folder (/var/www/SITE/frontend/public/images) in 775 with www-data in group and MY-USER in user (which is in the www-data group).
But it still doesn't work. It seems to me that I had to do something similar when I put the site online a year ago, but I don't remember.
